# laravel 5.1 image shows incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, sass, laravel-5.1

I have an `<img>` tag stored in the MySQL database that I want to get to my view in Laravel 5.1. The thing is I get it as an `<img>` tag and not as the image itself.

view code:

```
@foreach ($get_followee_posts as $post)
<form action="/html/tags/html_form_tag_action.cfm" method="post">
<textarea name="post_section" id="post_section" style="width:96%;height:90px;background-color:white;color:black;border:none;padding:2%;font:22px/30px sans-serif;">
{!! $post->full_post !!} </textarea>
 </textarea>
</form>
@endforeach
```

Controller Code:

```
$get_followee_posts= Post::whereIn('user_id',$followingNow->lists('id'))->get();
```

here's an exmaple post right for the db record (for example):

```
1st post!<img alt="heart" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/succodesign/love-is-in-the-web/512/heart-icon.png">
```

And here's a screenshot of the problem: (heart icon shown too large in the right. and good in the left side (before inserting a post).  Also it returns `<img>` tags and not an image).

I also user summernote for this foreach.If you have better alternative- I would like to hear about that.

Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to render your image inside the textarea? Also your screenshot is missing.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL or Sass?  What is the compiled output?

Comment: Yes I am trying to render the image inside the textarea (as part of a post).

Screenshot:
http://1.1m.yt/k5Fy6By.png

I am using mysql as my database.And I have mistakenly added sass. It is basically because I need to resize the rendered image - but I will deal with it later.

Answer (score -1):

Eventually I have managed to fix this issue.

created a div for the icons and resized them to 24x24.

```
<div class="followee_posts">

@foreach ($get_followee_posts as $post)

{!! $post->full_post !!} <br><br>

@endforeach
```

.scss file (followee_posts is relevant):

```
.test img, .icons img , .followee_posts img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

screenshot:

http://1.1m.yt/fuWvbts.png

Thanks to whoever tried to help.